# Upload files larger than upload_max_filesize

Tags: php, ajax, file-upload

Is it possible to somehow(ajax/...) upload files larger than upload_max_filesize(128M) and post_max_filesize(128M)(and smaller than 1GB)? I've tried to google it but I haven't found nothing except changing php.ini configuration(I can't do that, I use shared webhosting).

I appreciate any clues

Comment: Slice the file up into few parts each less than a limit and than put them together on the server

Comment: You could upload to something like Amazon S3 rather than your web server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are supporting modern browsers you can use the `FileReader` API to slice the files. This allows you to slice your file into an arbitrary number of small slices. You'll never run into the upload_max_filesize or post_max_filesize.

You will need to add some logic to reassemble the slices server-side but this isn't very involved.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could change the settings by ini_set. if the host did not disable the function ini_set in the global php.ini config.